# Pygame - Smooth Transform of Image/Surface

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a way to create a smooth transition between one image and another?

Say I have Image X and Image Y

```
ImageX = pygame.image.load('foo.png')
ImageY = pygame.image.load('oof.png')
```

Image X transforms into image Y when W = 5
Normally, I would just do this in the draw code:

```
if w == 5:
    screen.blit(ImageY, (100, 100))
else:
    screen.blit(ImageX, (100, 100))
```

But that just makes image X become replaced with ImageY, one frame its imageX, another frame its imageY

How would I make ImageX transition into ImageY smoothly? Like the transition attribute in css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign transparency (0-255) to surface with [set_alpha](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha)

```
ImageX.set_alpha(128)
```

and when you blit `ImageX` after `ImageY` then you should see both images.

```
blit(ImageY, ...)
blit(ImageX, ...)
```

You have to only change `set_alpha()` (from 255 to 0) in loop to get smooth efect.

```
if transparency > 0:
     transparency -= 1 

ImageX.set_alpha(transparency)

blit(ImageY, ...)
blit(ImageX, ...)
```

---

BTW: probably to use `set_alpha()` image has to use `convert()`, not `convert_alpha()`.

---

See my examples on GitHub: [pygame - transparency](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency)

Answer (score 1):

To set the alpha/transparency of images with per-pixel alpha, you need to use a little trick. You can create an intermediate surface, fill it with white and the desired alpha value and then blit it onto the other surface with the `pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT` flag. That will leave fully transparent pixels untouched and just change the transparency of the visible parts.

So if you want to fade one surface in and the other out, you just have to store their alpha values, change them every frame and then call the `change_alpha` function to get new surfaces with the right transparency. (I'm using text surfaces in this example, but it works with other surfaces/loaded images as well).

```
import pygame as pg


def change_alpha(orig_surf, alpha):
    """Create a copy of orig_surf with the desired alpha value.

    This function creates another surface with the desired alpha
    value and then blits it onto the copy of the original surface
    with the `BLEND_RGBA_MULT` flag to change the transparency."""
    surf = orig_surf.copy()
    # This surface is used to adjust the alpha of the txt_surf.
    alpha_surf = pg.Surface(surf.get_size(), pg.SRCALPHA)
    alpha_surf.fill((255, 255, 255, alpha))  # Set the alpha value.
    surf.blit(alpha_surf, (0, 0), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
    return surf


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 64)

    # The original surface which will never be modified.
    orig_surf = font.render('Enter your text', True, pg.Color('dodgerblue'))
    alpha = 255  # The current alpha value of the surface.

    # Surface 2
    orig_surf2 = font.render('Another text surface', True, pg.Color('sienna1'))
    alpha2 = 0

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        if alpha > 0:
            # Reduce alpha each frame.
            alpha -= 4
            alpha = max(0, alpha)  # Make sure it doesn't go below 0.
            surf = change_alpha(orig_surf, alpha)
        if alpha2 < 255:
            alpha2 += 4
            alpha2 = min(255, alpha2)
            surf2 = change_alpha(orig_surf2, alpha2)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        screen.blit(surf, (30, 60))
        screen.blit(surf2, (30, 60))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: intresting, how could i make it faster? @skrx

Comment: Just change the value by which the `alpha` is decreased or increased (`alpha -= 4`).